# Symfony 4 installation with composer faild

Tags: composer-php, symfony-3.3, symfony4

When I do `sudo composer create-project monolog/monolog Experience2` it succed: [image]

But When I try to install a fresh Symfony 4 application as describe in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/download): `composer create-project symfony/skeleton Experience2` it faild: [image]

I know about the warning message displayed by composer in fact about the information on [composer website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http) according to my understanding, the needed configuration can only be done in composer.json file which one I'll get only after successful istallation then how can I edit it ? since the installation does not succed (therefore there is no file such as ./Experience2/composer.json).

Comment: Which version of composer are you using? See `composer --version`. And please don't call `create-project` using sudo, that is not needed

Comment: compser --version donne: Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34 et quand je fais sudo apt-get install composer cela donne: composer is already the newest version (1.0.0~beta2-1).

Comment: That is not the most recent version of composer - try to update it through `sudo composer self-update`

Comment: I just solve the problem : sudo apt-get remove composer and I follow installation process from composer website. Notice that composer self-update did not work.